# Particle System not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, particle-system

So I'm working on a game for Android and iOS, and I wanted to make snow, so I added a particle system and it works fine in the editor, but when I built the game and tested it on Android it doesn't work. Is there a certain build configuration I need to do to make it work on Android, or something like that?

I'm using Unity Version **2017.2.0f3**

[image: Setup]

Comment: @Programmer The particle effect is showing in the editor, but not when I build it to Android.

Comment: @Programmer I tried that, but It doesn't work

Comment: @Programmer 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to version **2017.2.1f1** and all of a sudden it started working. So the problem was in the Unity version.